LaTeX: Prevent page breaks before \chapter
To modify a template file (.cls) so that it does not automatically insert a page break before \chapter, how can this be achieved?
Google provides that:
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\chapter}
  {\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}{\par\relax}
  {}{}
\makeatother

However, no matter where I insert this piece of code into the .cls file or the preamble, it does not work.
Another method is to use xpatch to apply a patch, but it still doesn't work.
So how can this requirement be fulfilled?

Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which document class you employ.

@Mico The .cls file is based on LaTeX's native "book".

May I ask why? Starting a new page is the whole point of chapters.

Try using [oneside] in the document class.
